# Mobile Vision API - Best practices to store QR code reads

Tags: java, android, android-vision

I am using the Mobile Vision API (latest version) in an Android application. I am following the examples from google (multi-tracker). Its working great, but now I am trying to store the QR code reads to an external resource, via API.

What are the best practices for this? I don't want to slow down processing of the QR Code reads due to the thread being hung up trying to make a API POST. Any examples would be great!